# Glass wall light issue

Tags: rendering, objects

I have a glass wall that is a half circle style. Is there a way to stop the glass distorting the images from within? It is affecting the inner stuff like real glass.. which for once, I actually don't want.

Comment: 1. I don't really see what you mean.. I guess you have a half sphere glass? 2. What Render engine do you use? 3. Did you try to adjust the IOR to fit your needs? In cycles for example for plain glass don't use the Glass shader. Instead use a mixed Shader containing Transparency and Glossy (if you wish use a fresnal input as mix-Factor)

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom left of your question and add more information. Add an image that shows your issue and images of your current material settings.

Comment: I followed your advice for using transparency and glossy and it worked perfectly! Thank you